# Update tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In one of my MySQL database, I have a table with two columns with no values for it.

I used the query

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = 'test', column2 = 'name';"
```

to update the table. It returned a result of

> Query OK Rows Affected 0  changed 0

When I executed `"select * from table_name;"`

it returned **Empty Set** with no updated values in table. Can you please suggest correct procedure for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, both are of the type varchar(20).

Comment: why are you using update on blank data just use insert.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from table_name;`

Is the correct statement to `SELECT` all rows from `table_name`.

Since this returns the empty set your table is empty and contains no rows/data.

To put rows/data into your table use the `INSERT` command:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2)
VALUES ('test', 'name');
```

After you have rows/data in your table THEN you can `UPDATE` them.

Answer (score 0):

If your table does not  contain any value for two fields then how can you update. Use `Insert` instead of `Update`.

Answer (score 0):

update in this manor

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```

or OR profile_4 = ''

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value WHERE column_name IS NULL OR column_name = '';
```